# how to put div in a for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

For parsing a list of articles, i have  this code to parse all the articles:

```
 while($article = $articles->fetch())
            {

                $date = strtotime($article['createdAt']);


                $formatted_date = date("F Y",$date);


            ?>

            <br />
            <div class="news-content">

                <div class="news-image">
                    <a href="post2.php?id=<?php echo $article['articleId']; ?>" class="news-image-anchor" style="background-image: url('blog/<?php echo $article['featuredImage']; ?>');"><?php echo $article['title']; ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="news-article">
                    <h3>
                        <span><?php $date = strtotime($article['createdAt']); echo /*date("F j",$date);*/ strftime('%e %B',$date) ?></span>
            <br />
                        <a href="post2.php?id=<?php echo $article['articleId']; ?>"><?php echo $article['title']; ?></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php

            } //end while loop

            ?>
```

What i want to achieve: only the first 5 `<div class="news-content">...</div>` should be shown. 
I know i have to do something with a `for loop` 
but i do not know exactly how to use the for loop for this situation...

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: add a `$counter++;` and `break;` while loop if `$counter>5`. [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: ..or read only the first 5 entries from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to limit a loop. One possibility is to use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. `for` is often a good option if you want something to happen a specific number of times. Adding something else like `fetch` into the continuation condition will mean it happens *up to* a specific number of times.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5 && $article = $articles->fetch(); $i++) {
    // output article
}
```